# Copy paste data to bottom last row on different worksheet with google sheet scrips

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to a script to work in which value from a specific range are pasted onto another sheet in a specific range. Problem is that not always the entire range of the input sheet is used and next time the function is used the data is pasted below the previously empty cells, see picture. Anybody any ideas?

[image: Database skips n lines that are not filled in with data in the input sheet]

```
    function submitData2() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var database = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data Logboek");
      var source = ss.getSheetByName('Logboek Melding');
      var dataToCopy = source.getRange('B2:J11');

      var lastRow = database.getLastRow();

      database.getRange('\'Logboek melding\'!B2:J11')
      .copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Data Logboek").getRange(lastRow + 1,1)
       ,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 
        }
```

Comment: Your code is not valid, let’s update it.

Comment: How do you mean not valid?

Comment: I mean syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

Your copying process seems confused:

1. You are selecting a range in your database Sheet using A1 notation, but you are referencing another Sheet.
2. You already have the `Data Logboek` Sheet saved in the `database` variable, there is no need to get it again from the SpreadsheetApp.
3. If the copying direction is `source -> database` you should call `toCopy` on a `source` range not the other way around.

### Solution

Using your variable declaration you can translate your copying process to this:

```
var dataToCopy = source.getRange('A1Notation'); // Source data to copy on database

dataToCopy.copyTo(
    database.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), // Destination
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, // Copy Paste Type
    false // Transpose
);
```

### Reference

[copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)